# How to fix xpath?

Tags: java, selenium

This is the xpath that i have to use: `"//*[@id="zona-mijloc"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/label/kbd"`

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"zona-mijloc\"]div/table/tr[1]/td[1]/label/kbd")).getText();
```

[That's the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7yyQ.png)

Comment: Paste your html as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select last element use `last()` as index:

1. `//*[@id='zona-mijloc']//tbody//tr[last()]//kbd`
2. `(//*[@id='zona-mijloc']//kbd)[last()]`

To get text in Selenium be sure the element is visible. You can wait for visibility of element using `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
String id = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='zona-mijloc']//tbody//tr[last()]//kbd"))).getText();
```

Comment: What did not work? What error do you get? Can you share URL?

Comment: https://www.pbinfo.ro/?pagina=judge-board&id_problema=3120&user=IosifHriscu

Comment: I need the id from the bottom of the page, just the last one. And no, I don't get any errors.

Comment: That's my code https://pastebin.com/iv1h1vff. Do you have any idea why after the first iteration it stops ? btw it works fine for the first one.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: @YosuvaA I saw it after I already solved the problem with xpath..thx for it.

Comment: @joseph_hrs about your code, yes there's small issue with your code

Comment: Do you have skype or smthng ? It's ok here too.

Comment: @joseph_hrs ask new question here, I'll help

Comment: i want help with that thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Xpath - `.//label[@for='id16401488']/kbd` Assuming there is no other match as same `xpath` in the html source code. If so use index of whichever `/kbd` you want.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: It's a site with submissions and you have to log in. This is the html code: https://pastebin.com/t8F7Gz6B

Comment: Search for kbd, there is 3 of them but i need just the last one.

Comment: Thats why we need html code, add we will be able to help u

Comment: we can't open this webpage

Comment: https://www.pbinfo.ro/?pagina=judge-board&id_problema=3120&user=IosifHriscu this should work, i need that id from the bottom.

Comment: and I saw you have commented that you want last id then use this xpath: .//label[@for='id16401478']/kbd

Answer (score 0):

I can't see all of the HTML for the elements referenced in your XPath, but you could try simplifying the path as such:

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tr[1]/td[1]/label/kbd")).getText();
```

If this does not work for you, I recommend posting the full page HTML so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this xpath and let me know how it goes.

```
//*[@id="zona-mijloc"]//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label/kbd
```

I am able to locate 3 elements with the above xpath. If wanted to capture text of all 3 elements, please try the below code.Else it will get the fist elements text.

### Java Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SW58291360 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./libs/chromedriver 4");
         WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.pbinfo.ro/?pagina=judge-board&id_problema=3120&user=IosifHriscu");
        List<WebElement> ids=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='zona-mijloc']//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label/kbd"));
        for(int i=0;i<ids.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ids.get(i).getText());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

### Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.implicitly_wait(15)    
driver.get("https://www.pbinfo.ro/?pagina=judge-board&id_problema=3120&user=IosifHriscu");

WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='zona-mijloc']//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label/kbd"))) #Wait for specific element 

table_rows= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='zona-mijloc']//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label/kbd")

for rows in table_rows:
    print rows.text

driver.quit()
```

### output

```
#16401488
#16401481
#16401478
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? if so what is the error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="zona-mijloc"]//div/table/tbody/tr/td/label/kbd"}

Comment: @joseph_hrs I have updated my anwer. please have a look. I am using your html code and it works fine for me

Comment: @joseph_hrs I have updated my answer with Java code which is working fine for me. Please try and let know me know.